# segmentation fault after destructor c++

Tags: c++

```
//Destructor Node
template<typename Data>
List<Data>::Node::~Node(){
  if(Nxt != nullptr)
    delete Nxt;
}

//Destructor List
template<typename Data>
List<Data>::~List(){
  Node* current = Head;
  while(current != nullptr){
    Node* Next = current->Nxt;
    delete current;
    current = Next;
  }
}
```

Guys, I implemented a list class with a struct node inside. The compilation of these destroyers has been successful and also the execution except that after having performed the assigned tasks, in the last line appears a "segmentation fault: 11. Since this error appeared only after implementing the destroyers I thought that the latter did not do their duty fully. Can you tell me if these destroyers are well made or not?

Comment: The shown code in this question does not meet stackoverflow.com's requirements for a [mre], and because of that it is unlikely that anyone here can conclusively determine the problem, but only guess, at the most. This question must be [edit]ed to show a minimal example, no more than one or two pages of code (the "minimal" part), that everyone else can cut/paste, compile, run, and reproduce the described problem (the "reproducible" part) ***exactly as shown*** (this includes any ancillary information, like the input to the program). See [ask] for more information.

Comment: In the `Node`'s destructor, you delete the node's successor. Since the while loop of the `List` destructor proceeds to the next node then, each node's destructor is called twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//Destructor List
template<typename Data>
List<Data>::~List(){
  Node* current = Head;
  while(current != nullptr){
    Node* Next = current->Nxt;
    delete current;
    current = Next;
  }
}
```

in this piece of code you have **Node* Next** local in while loop. which will be destroyed once loop exit.
in that situation it will call destructor of Node (~Node()) which *will destroy the the memory pointed by Next.*

Now inside ~List(), in next iteration current->Nxt is invalid and memory pointed by current pointer is already destroyed in last iteration.
so deleting a memory which is not valid will give "segmentation fault"

This is what I understand from this piece of code. I will suggest you to edit this post and add some minimal viable code to reproduce.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: How can I make both destroyers live together? How can I share tasks between the two?

Comment: one solution I can think of is, you declare Node* Next out side while loop.

Comment: @Michele let the `List` destructor do the work. If each `Node` can destroy other `Node`s, you have the be really careful A) that the `List` is not so long that it will run you out of automatic storage (the eponymous stack overflow) recursing through all of the `Node`s and B) when removing `Node`s from the `List` that you do not destroy the rest of the `List`'s `Node`s. In terms of responsibilities, it is the `Node`'s job to look after a node, but it is the `List`'s job to look after the list. Pushing some of the `List` responsibility onto the `Node` makes the node smarter than it needs to be.